# A Correct way to queue and canceling asynctasks

Tags: android, exception, gridview, android-asynctask

I have a `gridView`, wich contains about 300 elements. Each element has an `imageView`. When `getView()` is called, starts async image loader, which first looks for image in `LruCache`, then in external storage, and then in the net. Async tasks starts via `executeOnExecutor` with parameter `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.
And the problem is if I scroll grid view too fast, a lot of threads are created and app crashes with

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14980): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@42426f98 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41c6c800[Running, pool size = 128, active threads = 128, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 3]
```

Can anyone advice some method to control the amount of tasks to avoid such exceptions. 
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to use any of the image loading libraries like Picasso by Square or Universal Image Loader for loading images. These libraries allow for many configurations that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) for caching bitmaps using two methods

- Use a memory cache or
- Use a disk cache

You can also use third party libraries for caching images but there is one problem with this approach.
Few libraries doesn't support cache clearing options by default if images are cached on disk.